# Create a branch on GitHub ( no command line )

Tags: github

Is it possible to create a branch of a repository using the GitHub web based tool ( i..e not the command line).

I am the admin for the repository, but can not find any option for doing this.

Looking at the GitHub pages it only gives examples of how to do this using the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** (Nov 15 2013): It has been possible for a while to create branches on github.com

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository

---

(*This is no longer true*) No, currently it is not possible by using just the github.com webapp.

Comment: Yep - just got a reply from GitHub saying that. It is however possible using their Windows client, so that saved the day for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create branches by GitHub client.

Download & install

GitHub client for windows: http://windows.github.com/
GitHub client for Mac:     http://mac.github.com/